# Error when deploying to Tomcat6: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x0 but got 0x5ab93a08)

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I'm having this error when I deploy my war to Tomcat.  I am using Java 1.6.18, and Tomcat 6.0.24, Maven 2.2.1

```
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
Jul 12, 2010 8:22:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in dependencyCheck
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x0 but got 0x5ab93a08)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:171)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getBytes(JarInputStream.java:88)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionValidator.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4296)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1251)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:612)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jul 12, 2010 8:22:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

The war contains a JAX-WS webservice, with many dependencies.

The web.xml, sun-jaxws.xml, and pom.xml are essentially copies of my demo version which works fine.  Maven builds the war just fine, all of the projects i am consuming are  builting with Java 1.6.  I'm clueless as to what could be going on.

Why is the CRC expected to be 0x0?  Anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks much!

Comment: I just encountered a similar exception while trying to deploy a jaxws application to the new TomEE 1.0 release. Why are two similar exception being thrown from two disparate application servers, both involving jaxws?! Perhaps there is something else in the Jax-WS servlet that is causing it to fail and not be trapped?